# ado.net data services silverlight security

Tags: .net, wcf-security, wcf-data-services, astoria

I have a application where the validation is done in the web server side (in the page). and the control is passed to the sl client. The SL client makes call to the ado.net data services for its query and wcf service for writing to the DB.
How should I handle the security of the ado.net data services?
I use 
http://programmerpayback.com/2008/12/29/ria-security-102-using-aspnet-session-state-to-authenticate-web-service-calls/

to handle the wcf security.

Can I set a session on the ado.net side when the first request is made and on further requests validate against this session (given that cookies are maintained across).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about how to use ASP.Net Forms Authentication with the Data Services Silverlight client library [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/phaniraj/archive/2009/09/10/using-the-ado-net-data-services-silverlight-client-library-in-x-domain-and-out-of-browser-scenarios-ii-forms-authentication.aspx) . This blog post describes how to setup the server and client components so that calls to the data service are authenticated via Forms Authentication.